# MDK-ARM C: While loop won't break after interrupt

Tags: c, arm, keil

I want to break out the main loop after I press the button.

So I change the `isRunning` value in button press interrupt. But it didn't work.

hen I change the code `if(!isRunning){break;}` to `if(0 == isRunning){break;}` it will work like 70% of the time.

If I output the `isRunning` value in the loop. it will work every time. But I can't do the output while I am waitting for the `someOtherSignal` cause It tasks too long, I may miss the signal while I'm doing the output.

I want know why is it behaving like this. And how can I fix it.

in main.h

```
extern UINT8 isRunning;
```

in main.c

```
UINT8 isRunning;
....
//mainfunc
    isRunning = 1;
    output("before loop");
    while(!someOtherSignal){
        if(!isRunning){
            break;
        }
    }
    output("after loop");
....
```

in interrupt.c

```
void buttonPress_Routine(){
    isRunning = 0;
    output(isRunning);//output 0 when button pressed;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is deducing from the code that you aren’t changing the variable in your code so it can optimize reading it away. It doesn’t assume every variable could be changed elsewhere for efficiency. If you mark the variable as `volatile` it means that the variable can be modified outside the local code and should not be optimized away.

So changing the definition to

```
UINT8 volatile isRunning;
```

will tell the compiler not to optimize the variable access away.

Comment: @chux Thanks, autocorrect got me. No seduction necessary here :)